# bootstrap-select. How to live-search by some words?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I wish to find elements by some words, for example "Tom 55". How to do that?

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
    <option>Tom Foolery 55</option>
    <option>Tom Gordon 34</option>
    <option>Elizabeth Warren</option>
    <option>Mario Flores</option>
    <option>Don Young</option>
</select>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZLgyx

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet. I have added patterns in the `data-tokens`.

```js
$(function() {
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="box">
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Person</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-person" data-live-search="true">
    
                <option data-tokens="tom foolery 55 tom 55">Tom Foolery 55</option>
                <option data-tokens="tom gordon 34 tom 34">Tom Gordon 34</option>
                <option data-tokens="elizabeth warren">Elizabeth Warren</option>
                <option data-tokens="mario flores">Mario Flores</option>
                <option data-tokens="don young">Don Young</option>
                </select>

              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.box -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: Please tick the answer if it helps you to solve the issue

Comment: Thanks! But this method is not good for me. I can not generate all variants of tokes :(

Comment: But you anyway have to give a value to each word in order to work in the backend right?

Comment: i dont think it is possible to do dynamically since this is static content, maybe you can write a function in the backend to generate words according to inputs and get them to an array, and attach to the html

Comment: I need this for address field. Like a "Good str., h.13, fl. 75". And search have to work with query like: "good 13".

Comment: With bootstrap itself it is not possible. You need some function running back in order to achieve this